# Is there any logic to solve this?

Tags: c#

Someone ask me a very strange question which looks logically possible but I am newbie so I am asking here..

if input value is 5 return 7
and if input value is 7 return 5

**the condition is you cannot use if else statement nor switch case and nor loop**

how can I solve this? thanks

Comment: Please don't spam tags. I randomly deleted one

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. Also, C# is not C - they are two totally different languages. Please [edit] to remove the tag that is not applicable to your post.

Comment: hint - a specific bitwise operator. look at the bits of 5 and 7.

Comment: @KenWhite do you really think its homework question? its challenging if you looking it to logical way atleast its challenging to me don't you read the condition?

Comment: @SheikhFarzaib: Yes, because of the phrasing of the question, the restriction that was added, and the fact that you have demonstrated no effort to solve the problem yourself before posting  here.

Comment: @KenWhite I already spend 1 day to solve this problem and I couldn't that's why i am asking here should I mention my efforts in question?

Comment: If you don't show any effort in your post, we can't know you did. Information that isn't in your question doesn't exist, because the only thing we know is what's in your post. If you made efforts to solve the problem, then the efforts you made (not a statement that you made them, but the actual efforts) should be in your post.

Answer (score 5):

Among many other solutions, you could use

```cs
( 5 + 7 ) - i     // 12 - i
```

There's also

```cs
i ^ 5 ^ 7         // i ^ 2
```

Something clearer:

```cs
i == 5 ? 7 : 5    // Warning: Uses branching
```

Comment: Worth noting that 12 is 5 + 7.  and 2 is 5 ^ 7

Comment: @Wyck That's not how I obtained them, but that makes a lot of sense! Added.

Comment: True, but normally the point of these questions is to avoid branching due to branch-misprediction, and `?` still requires branching, the other options do not.

Comment: I think you mistake terseness for rudeness. I'm just trying to improve your post. I was simply adding a short one-liner comment, and now I see that `i ^ 5 ^ 7` uses XOR logic also. It's just giving you more options, please don't take it personally. Re branching: agree OP did not say so (and probably did not realize) but this sort of question pops up pretty frequently and the aim of the game is normally to avoid branching, so I assume that was the underlying intention, +1 for mentioning

Comment: @Charlieface, Re "*I think you mistake terseness for rudeness.*", I didn't say your tone was rude, I clearly said it was rude to say the answer was wrong based on unstated assumptions that the OP meant to ask something else.

Comment: Fair enough, apologies, didn't mean to come across that way